# Centering flex items inside a list

Tags: css, flexbox, centering

So I'm having a problem centering items from a menu I'm making.

I have tried to put `justify-content: center` but that does not seem to work. Can someone help?

Right now the menu is stuck on the left corner. I want to center it.

```css
.header2 {
  background-color: rgb(190, 13, 13);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
}

.menu li {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="header2">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Add `justify-content: center;` to your `.header2`. Does that not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nested flexbox (`.menu`) is set, by default, to `flex-grow: 0`, which means it won't occupy the full length of the parent.

Therefore, applying `justify-content: center` has no effect because there's no free space available in the container.

[image]

Adding `flex-grow: 1` provides the extra space you need:

[image]

Add this to your code:

```
.menu {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Also, since you're already using the semantically meaningful `nav` element, there's really no need for a nested list element. Try this simplified code instead:

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgb(190, 13, 13);
}

.menu a {
  padding: 25px 10px;
}

.menu a:hover {
  background-color: orangered;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Products</a>
  <a href="#">Contacts</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
.menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-grow: 1; /* or width: 100% */
}
```

if you want the elements evenly distributed by all the width.

And:

```
.menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-grow: 1; /* or width: 100% */
}
```

otherwise.